# Cannot open a .tif with color using .Net Image or Bitmap classes

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, tiff

I am attempting to open .tif files that have color in them (300 dpi, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) using the .Net Image and Bitmap classes.  I always get an "invalid parameter" error when the tiffs have color (works fine for black and white tiffs).  If anyone has source code on how to open a .tif with color in it I'd deeply appreciate it.  Below is what I'm attempting to do; this also fails when calling Bitmap.FromStream:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    using (Image img = Image.FromStream(fs)) {}
}
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me loading a 300 DPI, 24BPP color TIFF. Do you have any additional information about the color images?

Comment: TIFF is an acronym for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't open the image file is that the image maybe has compression format.
I also encounter this problem when I open a .gif image file.
I'm searching the solutions.
We can communicate each other.
showlie@163.com
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic problem is that one cannot use the .Net Image/Bitmap classes to reliably open color TIFFs.  Many of the various compression formats used to encode color TIFFs break the .Net Image/Bitmap class.

It seems to be a catch 22--you have to know the TIFF formatting information to know how to load it, but in .Net  one needs to load the Image/Bitmap class to read TIFF formatting information.

I think the answer to my question is, "this can't be done just using the .Net framework," and that I'll need to either buy a 3rd party control or create something myself in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I found the GDI(+) the limiting factor in dealing with TIFF. I had many "invalid parameter" issues on XP (in my case because of using 16bpp grayscale and tiled tiff). The same code worked flawlessly on Windows7/64bit.

For me, the free [LibTIFF.NET](http://www.bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) was the solution. ([StackOverflow using LibTIFF from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041783/using-libtiff-from-c-to-access-tiled-tiff-images)) Only con compared to GDI+: you'll have to roll your own BMP (uncompressed byte array to bmp conversion). I can provide you with examples if you like.

To diagnose your TIFF file type, you could use TiffDump [download link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm)
Using like tiffdump myfile.tif will produce an output like:

```
Magic: 0x4949 <little-endian> Version: 0x2a
Directory 0: offset 1669857288 (0x63880008) next 0 (0)
ImageWidth (256) SHORT (3) 1<33227>
ImageLength (257) SHORT (3) 1<24986>
BitsPerSample (258) SHORT (3) 1<16>
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Photometric (262) SHORT (3) 1<1>
FillOrder (266) SHORT (3) 1<1>
SamplesPerPixel (277) SHORT (3) 1<1>
XResolution (282) RATIONAL (5) 1<6400>
YResolution (283) RATIONAL (5) 1<6400>
PlanarConfig (284) SHORT (3) 1<1>
ResolutionUnit (296) SHORT (3) 1<2>
TileWidth (322) SHORT (3) 1<256>
TileLength (323) SHORT (3) 1<256>
```

Most likely such info can get you more specifc answers on StackOverflow.