# Reading tags of *.tiff and *.eps files

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, eps

i have to read tags of cmyk *.tiff and *.eps files. i use .net 3.5. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tiff I saw [this](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) in another thread. Looks quite interesting, but cannot tell how well it works.

Comment: i'm looking at libtiff.net and i simply dont understand how to use it. there is no any manual.

Comment: I think you will need to go through the original libtiff documenation: http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/ Additionally you can check this page which shows the differences in the .net version: http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/differences.aspx

Comment: BitMiracle LibTiff worked great for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041783/using-libtiff-from-c-to-access-tiled-tiff-images. There are several examples in the solution (I downloaded the source version), and basically the API is indeed the same as LibTiff as pointed out by Stefan Egli

Comment: LibTiff.Net 2.0 (just released) contains improved documentation and number of samples among other improvements and bug fixes. You may want to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the [EXIFextractor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exifextractor.aspx) library