# How do I check for corrupt TIFF images in C#?

Tags: c#, image, tiff

I searched on how to check if a TIFF file is corrupt or not. Most suggests wrapping the Image.FromFile function in a try block. If it throws an OutOfMemoryException, its corrupt. Has anyone used this? Is it effective? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

Please check out the freeware called LibTiff .NET. It has the function to check if every page in a TIF file is corrupted or not. Even partially corrupt also no problem

http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/

Thanks

Comment: LibTiff is a vast library for many different purposes. Can you point out a specific reference to detect corrupt TIFF files or some sample codes? That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Many tiff files won't open in the standard GDI+ .NET. That is, if you're running on Windows XP. Window 7 is much better. So any file which is not supported by GDI+ (i.e. fax, 16 bit gray scale, 48bpp RGB, tiled tiff, piramidical tiled tiff etc.) are then seen as 'corrupt'. And not just that, anything resulting in a bitmap over a few 100 MByte on a 32-bit system will also cause an out-of-memory exception.

If your goal is to support as much as possible of the TIFF standard, please start from LibTiff (derivates). I've used LibTiff.NET from BitMiracle (LGPL), which worked well for me. Please see my other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041783/using-libtiff-from-c-to-access-tiled-tiff-images)

Many of the TIFF utilities are also based on LibTIFF, some of them are ported to C#.NET. This would be my suggestion if you want to validate the TIFF.

As for the TIFF specification suggested in other replies: of course this gives you bit-level control. But to my experience you won't need to go that low to have good TIFF support. The format is so versatile that it will cost you an enormous amount of time to start support from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

It will only be corrupt in the sense that the frameworks methods cant open it.

There are some TIFF types that the framework cannot open -( In my case I cant remember the exact one, think it was one of the FAX type ones...)

That may be enough for you, if you are just looking a using the framework to manipulate images. After all I you cant open it, you cant use it...

ImageMagic - may give you more scope here

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the tiff, it may be difficult to see if its corrupt from a visual perspective, but if you have issues with processing an image, just create a function that does a basic test for this type of processing and handle the error?

Comment: assuming you dont want to validate the actual file contents to its strict specification...