# Help changing DPI in a TIFF file with JPEG compression

Tags: c#, image-manipulation, jpeg, tiff, freeimage

I have a **Tiff** file that comes from a scanner. It has a resolution of *300* dpi to start with. But later I need to change it to a different value, say *100*.

What's the best way to do this without losing the initial compression and color depth?

I already tried opening the **Tiff** with `Bitmap.FromFile()`, but I get an `OutOfMemoryException`, also used the FreeImage library, but here, if the Tiff is grayscale, it always uses **LZW** compression instead of **JPEG**. I know LZW is better, but **JPEG** is mandatory for me.

Comment: Some points: First, `dpi` (dots per inch) is related to output, not pixels (and is frequently misused like this). The term you want when working strictly with an image is `ppi` (pixels per inch). Second, JPEG by definition is lossy whereas LZW is not. (Though there is a [lossless JPEG standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG).) Third, changing the number of pixels in an image is termed `resampling` and when *reducing* the ppi of an image, you will always lose detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To load .tiff file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265491/to-load-tiff-file-in-c)

Comment: If you want to preserve compression, you can't decode the pixels with Bitmap.FromFile().  There is no way to get it back into JPEG form without losing quality.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OutOfMemoryException` is because .NET doesn't support TIFF with JPEG compression. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265491/to-load-tiff-file-in-c/4265702#4265702) for more.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the resolution, do you want the image to still be the same size in inches?  Or when you go to 100, are you expecting that the 300 pixels will now span 3 inches.

If you want it to be the same size, then you must resample the image to a smaller number of pixels (1/3).  In this case, you must decode the image, resample it, then re-encode it.  You will certainly lose information in the resample, and then you lose will more with the lossy JPEG compression that TIFF supports.

If you mean for the image to now appear to be 3 times larger, then you might be able to do this by editing just the MetaData of the TIFF.  The actual pixel data doesn't have to be touched to change the resolution.  libtiff can do this -- I don't know if LibTiff.NET can, but probably.

If you are looking at commercial solutions, my company's [DotImage Document Imaging](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage) can also do this.