# Add PresentationCore assembly reference in web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext, tiff

After reading [Using LibTiff from C# (to access tiled TIFF images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041783/using-libtiff-from-c-sharp-to-access-tiled-tiff-images) I decided to try to use .Net built in framework class [`TiffBitmapDecoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate the pdf from tiled TIFF image.

I got a big TIFF image around 4MB, which has tiles. I used iTextSharp before but it is not supporting tiles error.

But how do I add the `PresentationCore.dll` assembly in my web project reference?
I could not able to see in `Add Reference dialog`. I use `.Net 4.0 ASP.Net webform project`

[image]

It shows only System.Windows.Presentation

Also do any one processed tiled TIFF to pdf with .Net built in Framework classes with out using 3rd party libraries like LibTIFF?

Comment: I've had no issue adding a reference to `PresentationCore` in web projects. What framework version are you targeting? And what "flavour" (e.g. MVC, etc) of ASP.Net?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, we are using `.Net 4.0 ASP.Net webform project`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, attached screenshot for you

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place, by that screenshot. The assembly's name is `PresentationCore`. Not `System.Windows.PresentationCore`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`PresentationCore` is a part of **WPF**, which is a .NET Framework built-in feature. You should be able to add it easily for both MVC and classic ASP.NET for .NET Framework v3.5 or later.

Please note that the assembly name used by `PresentationCore.dll` is plain `PresentationCore`. It **does not have** any prefixes (e.g. System.PresentationCore, Microsoft.PresentationCore). Perhaps this is the reason you're having trouble finding it on the Framework Assemblies list.

[image]

Comment: No, the assembly **name** is `PresentationCore`. Namespaces and assemblies are orthogonal concepts, and when you're in the "Add Reference" dialog, you're dealing with assembly names. The `PresentationCore` assembly mostly contains types in namespaces starting `System.Windows.Media`.

Comment: @AoiKarasu I have as question about PresentationCore. Is it limited to just WPF? or, can it be used in any ASP.NET Core and MVC projects and even in Xamarin? Im creating a Core dll from a WPF project and I want to make it extensible across different project types. And not just limited to WPF.